# Reading in a text file as a numpy array with float values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I do not know python at all thus I have been unsuccessful in interpreting similar previous answers and using them.

I have a python script that I wish to execute in unix. The script uses an input file but I do not understand how to ensure that the input file is read as numpy float array.

My input file is called chk.bed and it has one column of numeric values

```
-bash-4.1$ # head chk.bed
7.25236
0.197037
0.189464
2.60056
0
32.721
11.3978
3.85692
0
0
```

The original script is -

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import numpy as np

#assume "fpkm" is a NumPy array of log2(fpkm) values

kernel = gaussian_kde(fpkm)
xi = np.linspace(fpkm.min(), fpkm.max(), 100)
yi = kernel.evaluate(xi)
mu = xi[np.argmax(yi)]
U = fpkm[fpkm > mu].mean()
sigma = (U - mu) * np.sqrt(np.pi / 2)
zFPKM = (fpkm - mu) / sigma
```

What I could understand up until now is to make sure the script is reading the file so I included **fpkm = open("chk.bed", 'r')** in the code.

However on executing the code - I get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./calc_zfpkm.py", line 10, in <module>
    kernel = gaussian_kde(fpkm)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/kde.py", line 88, in __init__
    self._compute_covariance()

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/kde.py", line 340, in _compute_covariance
    self.factor * self.factor)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1971, in cov
    X = array(m, ndmin=2, dtype=float)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

This seems to suggest that I am not reading in the file correctly and so the function gaussian_kde() cannot read in the values as float.

Can you please help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a file object to `gaussian_kde` but it expects a NumPy array, you need to use [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) first to load the data in an array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.loadtxt('chk.bed')
>>> arr
array([  7.25236 ,   0.197037,   0.189464,   2.60056 ,   0.      ,
        32.721   ,  11.3978  ,   3.85692 ,   0.      ,   0.      ])
>>> gaussian_kde(arr)
<scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde object at 0x7f7350390190>
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for replying. However i now get the error -         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./calc_zfpkm.py", line 7, in <module>
    fpkm = np.loadtxt('chk.bed')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 796, in loadtxt
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): NA

Comment: I also forgot to ask.. I need to output the file zfpkm as well which I  understand it probably doesnt. Can you help with that as well ?

Comment: @user2695213 Have a look at [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Comment: But that would output the result. Do you have any suggestion for the above mentioned error ?

Comment: @user2695213 Your file contains some non-numeric data(`'NA'` in this case), so `loadtxt` cannot convert them to float.

Answer (score -2):

Here you can find the

### R script for zFPKM normalization.

I inspired from the python code which has given above and also at this link:https://www.biostars.org/p/94680/

```
install.packages("ks","pracma")
```

```
library(ks)
```

```
library(pracma)
```

/* fpkm is an example data */

fpkm <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,5,5,5,6,6,78,8,89,8,8,8,2,2,2,1,1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,2,2,3,23,2,3,23,4,2,2,4,23,2,2,24,4,4,2,2,4,4,4,2,2,4,4,2,2,4,2,45,5,5,5,3,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,2,2,3,23,2,3,23,4,2,2,4,23,2,2,24,4,4,2,2,4,4,4,2,2,4,4,2,2,4,2,45,5,5,5,3,2,2)

```
 xi=linspace(min(fpkm),max(fpkm),100)
```

```
fhat = kde(x=fpkm,gridsize=100,eval.points=xi)
```

/* here I put digits=0. if I you do not round the numbers(yi) the results are a little bit changing.*/

```
yi=round(fhat$estimate,digits=0)
```

```
mu=xi[which.max(yi)]
```

```
U=mean(fpkm[fpkm>mu])
```

```
sigma=(U-mu)* (sqrt(pi/2))
```

```
zFPKM = (fpkm - mu) / sigma
```

### Btw, I have a question.

### Can I apply the same approach to RPKM?

Cankut CUBUK

Computational Genomics Program - Systems Genomics Lab

Centro de Investigación Príncipe Felipe (CIPF)

C/ Eduardo Primo Yúfera nº3

46012 Valencia, Spain

http://bioinfo.cipf.es ​